# Best practices when designing a News Website?

Tags: website-design, news, newsfeed

Can you give me some "Do's & Don'ts" about UX on news web design. Things like typefaces, colors, white-spacing, information architecture and so on... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "Do's & Dont's" exclusively for news pages.
You can/should apply best practices every other content heavy page is using.

Most important in my opinion:

• Create a content structure the user actually can grasp, news site often are not using a transparent structure which makes it nearly impossible for users to have a decent experience.

• Use images and videos - thats pretty obvious, but its a really good way to unravel the content and make it more appealing to users that don't like to read a lot.

• Tell the user how long it approximately will take him to read an article, this is often used in blogs but its really powerful in my opinion. Telling the user right away that it takes 10 minutes to read might save him the time opening and closing the article because he is arriving at work in 5 minutes.

You can read those articles regarding content heavy design:

https://usabilitygeek.com/designing-content-heavy-websites/

https://constructive.co/insights/best-practices-for-content-heavy-website-design/

And here is some inspiration for good content heavy design:
https://www.dtelepathy.com/blog/inspiration/14-beautiful-content-heavy-websites-for-inspiration